# Manejo de Sesiones no valida

Tags: php, validación, session

tengo el siguiente problema:

configuración para el servidor:

```
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
```

estoy tratando de validar si la sesiones esta activa

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_name('PruebaSesion');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['prueba']='No Existe Sesión, se procede a crearla';
    echo $_SESSION['prueba'];
}else{
    echo 'Sesion Habilitada';
    echo var_dump($_SESSION);
}
```

Esperaba que al hacer refresco imprimiera el segundo mensaje pero no lo hace se mantiene imprimiendo: "No Existe Sesión, se procede a crearla";

Comment: y si cambias tu condicional y preguntas si existe $_SESSION['prueba'] solo por probar ? (no se mucho de php)

Comment: la idea es saber si existe cualquera variable $_SESSION

Comment: El error está en que primero debes llamar `session_start()` antes de poder trabajar con la variable `$_SESSION`. [Nota (manual de php):](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) Para usar sesiones basadas en cookies, session_start() debe ser llamada antes de imprimir cualquier cosa en el navegador.

Comment: @CesarRomero Pero si declara session_Start() antes de la condición siempre entraría al else a no ser que cambie la condición por una variable de sesión específica , en este caso sería prueba

Comment: claro @CamiloVasquez con la nota que saque de la documentación, eso quiere decir que no puede realizar esa comparación, debe buscar otra forma de comparar. Por ejemplo `session_id()`

Comment: no funciona tu ejemplo me sigue dando el mismo problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder acceder a la variable de session debes llamar primero a session_start.

Debes hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(! isset($_SESSION['prueba'])){

    $_SESSION['prueba']='No Existe Sesión, se procede a crearla';
    echo $_SESSION['prueba'];
} else {

    echo 'Sesion Habilitada';
    echo var_dump($_SESSION);
}
```

Por lo regular se declara una variable `$_SESSION['id']` o su equivalente que guarda el id o código del usuario que ha accedido a tu web.

Pero antes de acceder a cualquier variable de sesión se debe usar `session_start`

Asi:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(! isset($_SESSION['id'])){

    header('Location: ./login.php');
    exit();
} 
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

// Se consulta base de datos para ver si existe el usuario si no refeccionar al login
```